# What happens to the radius of a circle on SVG when we apply a matrix transformation to it?

Tags: svg, transform

For example, given that I have this circle:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Now I have the same circle with a matrix transformation:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red" transform="matrix(3 1 -1 3 30 40)" />
</svg>
```

Why the circle is bigger now?

I was reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) but I didn't understand what happens to the circle. For the rectangle, it seems it calculates 4 new coordinates for it. But for the circle, it seems it calculates one new point, which is the new centre of the circle, and then something happens to the radius of the circle which I don't know what it is.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined

Comment: Nice, that will be useful to do what I want, but I still don't understand why the circle scales. For example, at this pen, I put a circle on each point after calculating the matrix, but it doesn't match where the circle is: https://codepen.io/matheussilvasantos/pen/GRqWBKv?editors=1000.

Comment: because 3 > 1 therefore it gets bigger.

Comment: How does it get bigger? Does it change the cartesian points of the circle? The circle has only one point which is in the center, what is changed to scale the circle?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've updated my example on CodePen and now I can see: https://codepen.io/matheussilvasantos/pen/GRqWBKv. The four points around the circle are considered for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformations can be thought of like this (although this isn't how they are implemented):

1. Work out all the points that you'd draw
2. map every point from step 1. to the transformed point you get by multiplying by the matrix
3. draw all those transformed points

Or alternatively imagine you drew the circle on an elastic sheet and then stretched the sheet uniformly.